# Connection Refused error on Google Chrome for Web applications

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, connection, glassfish-3, sunone

I am using Sunone 6.1 and Glassfish 3.1.2 webservers to run my application. My applications are working smoothly on Internet Explorer, but on Google Chrome I get an error "Connection Refused" with no further detailed description.

I connect to server using localhost and port number

Although, initially applications were running fine on Google Chrome also. I am unable to trace since when did the application stopped working on Chrome as I use my application on multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the port connection. Restarting the system solved the issue !